# potentiation matrix with no looping

Tags: r, matrix

I don't find function for my problem. I have matrix A.

```
 A<-matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),3,3)
```

I want calculated A^13,not elelement with element, but row with column.
Example for A^2

```
A%*%A
```

I can do with looping, but my question is: is there easy way or function for calculated this?

My result for A^13 must be:

```
[1 13 78]
[0  1 13]
[0  0  1]
```

Comment: never heard of *potentiation* matrix in that context, searching for *power* would have given you a few answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expm`

```
 library(expm)
 A%^%13
 #   [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    1   13   78
 #[2,]    0    1   13
 #[3,]    0    0    1
```

#### Benchmarks

On a smaller matrix

```
 set.seed(42)
 A <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100*100, replace=TRUE), 100, 100)
 f1 <- function() Reduce("%*%", replicate(200, A, FALSE))
 f2 <- function() A%^%200

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), unit="relative", times=25L)
 # Unit: relative
 #expr      min       lq   median      uq      max neval
 #f1() 237.8381 237.6059 235.6788 239.053 225.3443    25
 #f2()   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.000   1.0000    25
```

Comment: This is nice easy way. Thank you.

Comment: @Nejc Galof No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("%*%", replicate(13, A, FALSE))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   13   78
# [2,]    0    1   13
# [3,]    0    0    1
```